# $ is not a function in drupal 7 theme

Tags: theming, javascript

```
$(function(){
  $('.slider').mobilyslider({
    content: '.sliderContent',
    children: 'div',
    transition: 'horizontal',
    animationSpeed: 500,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 9000,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    bullets: true,
    arrows: true,
    arrowsHide: true,
    prev: 'prev',
    next: 'next',
    animationStart: function(){},
    animationComplete: function(){}
  });   
});
```

I am integrating the above JavaScript file in a Drupal theme, but it is giving me the "$ is not function" error. I googled it, and changed the code bro the below, but it doesn't work either.

```
(function($) {
  $('.slider').mobilyslider({
    content: '.sliderContent',
    children: 'div',
    transition: 'horizontal',
    animationSpeed: 500,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 9000,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    bullets: true,
    arrows: true,
    arrowsHide: true,
    prev: 'prev',
    next: 'next',
    animationStart: function(){},
    animationComplete: function(){}
  });   
})(jQuery);
```

The above code gives me following error:

> `$('.slider').mobilyslider` is not a function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first error you were getting was because `$` isn't defined as `jQuery` in Drupal 7, to avoid conflicts with other libraries. Adding the closure fixed that, as in your second code example.

As long as the mobilyslider library is definitely loaded into the page, the problem is probably that you're attaching the event before the DOM is ready...so the elements you're trying to attach to don't exist yet.

You could use the standard `$(document).ready()` method to solve this if you want to, or else use Drupal JS behaviours. For Drupal 7 that code would look like this:

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('.slider', context).mobilyslider({
        content: '.sliderContent',
        children: 'div',
        transition: 'horizontal',
        animationSpeed: 500,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 9000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        bullets: true,
        arrows: true,
        arrowsHide: true,
        prev: 'prev',
        next: 'next',
        animationStart: function(){},
        animationComplete: function(){}
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Be sure to pass in `context` to your jQuery selector for reusability.

See [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) for more info.

Comment: good answer better then my own :) I vote for this one! +1 :)

Comment: i am integrating this in my theme, so can you please tell me what should be the context value ??

Comment: `context` is passed in automatically you won't need to pass anything for that var

Comment: if i am integrating in drupal theme, then i should write theme name instead of module name right ?

Comment: and do i need to change anything in mobilyslider function ?

Comment: It doesn't matter to be honest, so long as that string is unique (so your theme name is a good one, yes). I've no idea if you need to change anything mobilyslider I'm afraid, I've never used it

Comment: still it is giving  $('.slider', context).mobilyslider is not function error....

Comment: @Clive how can i write this in document.ready() function ??

Comment: You don't need to, putting it inside a behaviours `attach` function will do the same thing. I suspect the mobilyslider library is missing from your page source

Comment: mobility library is loading in page..i checked page source..

Answer (score 3):

check [this](http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/drupal-theming-jquery-basics-inc-drupal-behaviors) out

I think you must store your js as drupal behavior:

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.some_name = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $('.slider').mobilyslider({
        content: '.sliderContent',
        children: 'div',
        transition: 'horizontal',
        animationSpeed: 500,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 9000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        bullets: true,
        arrows: true,
        arrowsHide: true,
        prev: 'prev',
        next: 'next',
        animationStart: function(){},
        animationComplete: function(){}
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Updated the code after @clives [tip](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors)

Comment: That's not the correct code for Drupal 7 behaviours, see http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors

Comment: can you give me some idea exactly what should be at some_name ??

Comment: I'm not a theme developer, but in case of a module it can be the module name. so I guess it should be your theme name

Answer (score 0):

The way you include your jQuers code is fine. There's a problem with the `mobilyslider` function. My guess is that you are relying on a jQuery plugin which isn't included.

Comment: Plugin is working fine in html template..